# android phonegap external wordpress image not loading in index.html

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, whitelist

I am damn tired by googling & searching in stackoverflow but none of the solutions are working for me.

I have a static app that i developed. now upon executing in android now in android simulator and real device images are not loading from external url.

any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Note:
I have already installed whitelist plugin
I have already have this below meta tag in my html file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *; img-src * filesystem: data:">
```

I have added :

```
 <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

in my res/xml/config.xml

let me know anything else i am missing in order to show an image from http://website/image.png

Thanks,
Ahsan Ali

Comment: clue: when i make target sdkversion to 28, images come brocken, but when i make it lower then 28, images get loaded

Answer (score 0):

ok the issue is resolved.

In order to load external url you have to put https:// protocol. now from api level 28, you must put https:// for the images

WARNING: Don't put a lot of high quality images because it will crash your app too.